# Why is my C++ program's assembly output full of .ascii with no assembly code?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc

I am compiling a C++ file into a static library with CMake and I am modifying the Makefile that CMake generates by adding the -S -fverbose-asm flags to the gcc command to get the assembly output, however the resulting .cpp.s file is filled with .ascii lines with what looks like hexadecimal data, and contains no assembly instructions, like the following:

```
.ascii  "\346+\274\004@\226\032!n\247<)\212\264\205\377*\204\275\364e"
.ascii  "\314\026\270vi\263\373\327\n\367$\332\035\364N\212\316\254\324"
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this, and how I can get legible assembly instructions instead?

Version of gcc: 5.4.0

Comment: Show C++ source please, and g++ version. Also check on godbolt.org if you can reproduce.

Comment: What happens if you decompile the object files with `nm` or `objdump` - or even just hexdump them in this case? Are the same strings there?

Comment: Looks like character codes for a more complex character set than ASCII.

Comment: Also make sure you are not using LTO. That seems to produce the output you describe.

Comment: @Jester: That would make sense, GCC is probably using `.ascii` as a somewhat compact way to emit raw binary in a format the assembler doesn't know about (GIMPLE).  The alternative would be `.byte 12,34,...` which is 2 to 4 source bytes per output byte, similar to ASCII with octal.  Or `.long` or `.quad` would come closer to 2 source bytes per output byte.

Comment: objdump -dS myfile.cpp.o just outputs: file format elf64-x86-64, I may be doing something wrong with objdump, not familiar with it. What is LTO?

Comment: Link time optimization, enabled using `-flto` usually. Should see plenty of `lto` strings in your `.s` file.

Comment: Yes indeed, I do see -flto in the .cpp.s file at the beginning with all the flags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably compiled with Link Time Optimization enabled (`gcc -flto`), which makes "fat" object files that also contain GCC's intermediate representation of the program logic alongside regular asm.  (So whole-program optimization can happen at link time, allowing inlining across source files and further optimizations that weren't possible when only a prototype was visible.)  Or if you link with a linker that isn't aware of LTO, it will ignore the LTO sections and just use the regular machine-code sections.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-Overview.html

**GCC uses `.ascii` with octal escapes as a somewhat compact (in the asm source) way to emit raw binary in a format the assembler doesn't know about (GIMPLE bytecode).**

The alternative would be `.byte 12,34,...` which is 2 to 4 source bytes per output byte, similar to ASCII with octal which gives 1 to 4. (1 for any byte in the printable ASCII range).

`.long 0xabcd220c, 0x...` or `.quad` would come closer to 2 asm source bytes per output byte.

This efficiency consideration is only for the `.s` temporary file that GCC will feed to `as`; in the `.o` the data will be in binary (in an object-file section with a special name).  GCC wants a format that's fast to serialize into in GCC, and fast for the assembler to parse and convert back into bytes.  Presumably the double-quoted string for `.ascii` makes parsing simple.